# Standard input to an interactive bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a bash script that uses a series of prompts from the user (using echo) and stores the input in a variable (using read). The prompts and inputs look something like this:

```
echo "Name of Folder?"
read foldername
echo "Value1?"
read value1
echo "value2?"
read value2
echo "value3?"
read value3
echo "value4?"
read value4
echo "value5?"
read value5
echo "value6?"
read value6
```

The contents of input look like this

```
Foldername
41
0.83
0.38
-9
5 5 5
```

I now need to iterate this script over a foldername1...n with the same values and I am trying to do that with 
`./script < inp` however the script chokes on itself and does not execute. I have tried other methods such as, `<<EOF`,`<<< "value1..n"`and none of these methods worked. could someone help me understand how one could do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please *show* us the script, and the contents of `inp` (so we can see exactly how it contains the values) - you can [edit] your question to include this information

Comment: Get to know Bash - read the Bash guides at www.tldp.org (Bash Guide for Beginners, Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide)

Comment: Hi steeldriver, the question is edited with some more specific information.